# This strange type [T*]

Tags: scala

For example, I have following function that concatenates beginings and endings producing all possible variants of concatenation as result:

```
def mixer1(begin: String, beginings: String*)(end: String, endings: String*) =
  for (b <- (begin +: beginings); e <- (end +: endings)) yield (b + e)
```

Actually what function does is not impotant, I want to rewrite it this way:

```
  def mixer2(begin: String, beginings: String*):Function2[String, Seq[String], Seq[String]] = {
    return new Function2[String, Seq[String], Seq[String]] {
      def apply(end:String, endings:Seq[String]) = for(b <- (begin +: beginings); e <- (end +: endings)) yield b+e
    }
  }
```

Obviously, second one wouldn't work as expected because apply's second parameter has type Seq[String] but not String* (howewer they both compile to Seq[String]):

```
scala> mixer1("a","b")("c","d")
res0: Seq[java.lang.String] = ArrayBuffer(ac, ad, bc, bd)

scala> mixer2("a","b")("c","d")
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("d")
 required: Seq[String]
       mixer2("a","b")("c","d")
```

How can I (if I can) redefine mixer2 function?

Comment: Having only thought a short time about this, I think this should actually work. You could ask on #scala or look if you find this problem in the bug tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
def mixer2(begin: String, beginings: String*) = {
    new ((String, String*) => Seq[String]) {
      def apply(end: String, endings: String*) = for(b <- (begin +: beginings); e <- (end +: endings)) yield b+e
    }
}
```

We use type inference on `mixer2` to get the correct type. This means `return` must be removed, but that's ok, since it was unnecessary (and, generally advised against on Scala). The big trick is using the `A => B` syntactic sugar for `Function` to be able to use `String*`. Then just change `apply` as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can go the easy way:

```
def mixer2 = mixer1 _
```

Answer (score 0):

As in your example, you can just do this

```
implicit def toSeq[T](x: T): Seq[T] = List(x)
```

But when it comes to more arguments, like

```
mixer2("a","b")("c","d","e")
```

There seems to be no suitable solution, although there has been an implicit conversion from Array[T] to Seq[T]. Because T* is a syntax candy, ("c","d","e") will be seen as 3 arguments. Compiler cannot recognize which ones form an array.

So I wonder what is your actual scenario, this example looks strange.
If you just want a part of the function, @Debilski's solution is a great way.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape without even naming the intermediate return type.

```
def mixer2(begin: String, beginings: String*) = new {
  def apply(end: String, endings: String*) =
    for (b <- (begin +: beginings); e <- (end +: endings)) yield b+e
}
```

People will try to tell you this involves reflection.  Surprisingly enough, it does not.

Comment: Can you expand on how this doesn't use reflection? It looks like it does to my newbie eyes (on 2.8.0).

Comment: The only way it should look like it's using reflection is if you look, and it's using reflection.  I suggest looking! There are some very similar constructions which would involve reflection, but this one doesn't.